# Calculate Average of cells that two requirements

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, filter, average, nested-if

How would I work out the average of a range where it has to meet two requirements.

In the example below, I would like to calculate the average 'Score' of all of the 'Type 1' results that are within August 2022.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=AVERAGE(FILTER(C:C; YEAR(A:A)=2022; MONTH(A:A)=8; B:B="Type 1"))
```

or even `AVERAGEIFS` can be used

Comment: not having any luck with that (even with AVERAGEIFS)

Comment: @comiconor can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: Nevermind. - I just noticed 'YEAR' was spelt wrong in your formula. - Now working perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: @comiconor yup, sry, fixed

Comment: =8 not =B  month

Comment: @Osm thats an 8 not B

Comment: ah i was looking to the edit before and he has the date format wrong there is no month 8   in date column. X_X

Comment: How would the formula be if you added another condition. E.g column D now has a 'Name category. So, I would like to calculate the average 'Score' of all of the 'Type 1' results that are within August 2022 but are submitted by 'Dave'.

Comment: @comiconor `=AVERAGE(FILTER(C:C; YEAR(A:A)=2022; MONTH(A:A)=8; B:B="Type 1"; D:D="Dave"))`

Comment: @player0 Last question if you don't mind. - In that formula, can it return the result of '0' if there are no matches to the condition. - At the moment I just get a #div/0. This formula is contained within an IF statement for my sheet. =IF(A2="August 2022", AVERAGE(FILTER('Results Query'!AH:AH, YEAR('Results Query'!A:A)=2022, MONTH('Results Query'!A:A)=8, 'Results Query'!D:D="Queries")))

Comment: @comiconor sure, try: `=IFERROR(AVERAGE(FILTER('Results Query'!AH:AH, YEAR('Results Query'!A:A)=2022, MONTH('Results Query'!A:A)=8, 'Results Query'!D:D="Queries")), 0)`

Answer (score 0):

- Fix th date format first there is no August in your dates

[image]

> To look like this

[image]

Try this, or see [**Example**](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KiVwULl72RGV8uiyCyW0WLRN_vZv96QjeIW5K4LyoI0/edit?usp=sharing)

```
=IFERROR(AVERAGE(FILTER(E2:E, YEAR(B2:B)=2022, MONTH(B2:B)=8, C2:C="Type 1",D2:D=F5 )),0)
```

[image]

> To get Unique Names in cell `I2`

```
=UNIQUE(D2:D)
```

Comment: the date is not necessarily wrong. depends on the locale settings but for example, in my country, we start dates with the day so 01/08/2022 = 1st Aug 2022

Comment: How would the formula be if you added another condition. E.g column D now has a 'Name category. So, I would like to calculate the average 'Score' of all of the 'Type 1' results that are within August 2022 but are submitted by 'Dave'.

Comment: @comiconor the answer is updated with the example sheet

Comment: Last question if you don't mind. - In that formula, can it return the result of '0' if there are no matches to the condition. - At the moment I just get a  #div/0

Comment: In my example returns  #div/0 ?!

Comment: Its return No Match see [this](https://i.imgur.com/1eKefdP.png)

Comment: `0` indicate that the record is present but the avrage is `0` if you deal with negative and positive values, just keep in mind, ill [change](https://i.imgur.com/MqtNNBy.png) it anyways.

Comment: I can't seem to get mine working. - The working one I'm using has an IF statement in front of this formula. It works fine, but cannot get it to return 0 when appropriate. My forumla :  -- - -   =IF(A2="August 2022", AVERAGE(FILTER('Results Query'!AH:AH, YEAR('Results Query'!A:A)=2022, MONTH('Results Query'!A:A)=8, 'Results Query'!D:D="Queries")))

Comment: I added the example sheet to the anser and [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KiVwULl72RGV8uiyCyW0WLRN_vZv96QjeIW5K4LyoI0/edit?usp=sharing) use it directly, im checking your formula now.